# Importing CSV in magento

Tags: magento, csv

I have a csv with column are seperated by delimeter ';' and column value enclosed is set to none. I have done the same configuration in Magento->System->Import/Export->Dataflow-Profiles.

But when i import the csv in my magento installation i got an error.

Can not find required columns: sku

Here is my sample csv data ->

```
store;associated;config_attributes;websites;attribute_set;type;category_ids;sku;has_options;name;image;small_image;thumbnail;url_key;url_path;options_container;image_label;small_image_label;thumbnail_label;price;weight;status;visibility;enable_googlecheckout;tax_class_id;description;short_description;special_from_date;qty;min_qty;use_config_min_qty;is_qty_decimal;backorders;use_config_backorders;min_sale_qty;use_config_min_sale_qty;max_sale_qty;use_config_max_sale_qty;is_in_stock;low_stock_date;notify_stock_qty;use_config_notify_stock_qty;manage_stock;use_config_manage_stock;stock_status_changed_auto;use_config_qty_increments;qty_increments;use_config_enable_qty_inc;enable_qty_increments;is_decimal_divided;stock_status_changed_automatically;use_config_enable_qty_increments;product_name;store_id;product_type_id;product_status_changed;product_changed_websites;meta_title;meta_description;custom_design;page_layout;country_of_manufacture;msrp_enabled;msrp_display_actual_price_type;gift_message_available;style;special_price;msrp;color;is_recurring;size;meta_keyword;custom_layout_update;special_to_date;news_from_date;news_to_date;custom_design_from;custom_design_to
admin;;size,color;;Default;configurable;17,51;81341;1;2 PC. Stretch lace cut out chemise with satin bow accents and matching g-string.;/l/a/large-RC-original-1411.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1411.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1411.jpg;2-pc-stretch-lace-cut-out-chemise-with-satin-bow-accents-and-matching-g-string;2-pc-stretch-lace-cut-out-chemise-with-satin-bow-accents-and-matching-g-string.html;Block after Info Column;;;;10;0;Enabled;Catalog, Search;Yes;None;2PC.Stretch lace cut out chemise with matching g-string O/S ;2PC.Stretch lace cut out chemise with matching g-string O/S ;;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0.00000000000;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;2 PC. Stretch lace cut out chemise with satin bow accents and matching g-string.;0;configurable;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;;O/S,RED;lingerie;Default;simple;;8134222003;0;2 PC. Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ring accents.;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;2-pc-lace-triangle-bra-and-strappy-g-string-set-with-heart-ring-accents;2-pc-lace-triangle-bra-and-strappy-g-string-set-with-heart-ring-accents.html;Block after Info Column;;;;10;1;Enabled;Not Visible Ind;Yes;None;2PC.Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ri;2PC.Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ri;;100;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0.00000000000;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;2 PC. Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ring accents.;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;RED;;O/S;;;;;;;
admin;8134222003,;size,color;lingerie;Default;configurable;16,34;81342;1;2 PC. Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ring accents.;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;/l/a/large-RC-original-1430.jpg;2-pc-lace-triangle-bra-and-strappy-g-string-set-with-heart-ring-accents;2-pc-lace-triangle-bra-and-strappy-g-string-set-with-heart-ring-accents.html;Block after Info Column;;;;10;0;Enabled;Catalog, Search;Yes;None;2PC.Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ri;2PC.Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ri;;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;0.00000000000;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;2 PC. Lace triangle bra and strappy g-string set with heart ring accents.;0;configurable;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Did you try to use comma (,) as a separator? Also make sure the file encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Yeah i have also tried comma(,) and the file encoding is UTF-8.Actually i have exported the table from my wamp installation in csv format.

Comment: There is a difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM. Open the file with notepad++ (if you can) and you can change the encoding from there.

Comment: I have added comma(,) as a seperator and column values are enclosed in "",also changed the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM.But i get the error.Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100

Comment: that's looks lie a totally different issue.